# How do I allow a servlet filter in the root context to work on other contexts?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I have a WAR file deployed to the root context (`/`) on Tomcat 8, which has a servlet filter attached to it. The filter checks to see if the user is logged in and if not redirects them to the login page. I also have other contexts deployed in the same Tomcat instance at `/app1` and `/app2`. I want the filter in the root context to also apply to the other contexts, so I don't have to maintain three nearly identical filters (one for each context).

The problem is any URL that falls in the other contexts is not being handled by the filter in the root context. For example, the URI `/foo/bar` is caught by the filter (because it doesn't correspond to one of the other contexts), but `/app1/foo/bar` is not caught.

I've tried configuring the filter to catch everything by modifying the filter mapping in the web.xml file:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and I've also tried explicitly adding each context:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/app1/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/app2/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but neither approach worked. I assume it's a security issue--the other contexts need to explicitly allow the root filter. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get this to work. Web applications are independent. Requests are mapped to web applications before any Filters or Servlets are mapped.

You best bet with Tomcat (assuming you don't want multiple filter definitions) would be to re-implement your filter as a Tomcat Valve and configure the Valve on the Host.

Comment: You could also enable cross-context calls as described in [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html) and then make use of [javax.servlet.ServletContext.getRequestDisptacher(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher-java.lang.String-) to invoke `app1` or `app2`. It could be messy though and it creates direct coupling between the root application and the others.